# How to build a chained expression methods Any

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, expression

I'm trying to evaluate an expression of chained Any method call:

Well, I have a notation as string like this:

```
A[B[C]]
```

The A letter is a property and it is a collection. B is a property of A and it is a collection too. C is a property of B and it is the end of chain.

That notation will be right like below:

```
A.Any(a => a.B.Any(b => b.C == value)
```

I'm trying to write reflection code to solve this problems using a recursive solution but I'm fail.

If I'm not clear, ask me please.

Could anyone help me?

Regards

Comment: So you want to be able to parse some arbitrary string into a chain of `Any` calls?

Comment: Try `A.Select(s => s.B.Any(b => b.c == value))`

Comment: @Rodolfo That would give him an `IEnumerable<bool>` rather than a `bool`, which is probably not what he wants.

Comment: It would be much easier if you use the typical "path" notation, e.g. `A.B.C`

Comment: I want to create it using expression code: Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new [] { type }, A, predicate)